# Tensorflow: CNN is not learning at all

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I just created my own CNN which reads data from the disk and tries to learn.
But the weights don't seem to learn at all, they all stay randomized.

The biases change only a bit. I already tried to use grayscale images, without success. I also tired to reduce my dataset to only 2 classes which in my opinion should have worked. But the measured accuracy is below 50% (Maybe I am calculating the accuracy false)

Here is some code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, classes])
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([12*12*64, 1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, classes]))
}
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([classes]))
}

pred = model.conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob, imgSize)

with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    while(step < epochs):
         batch_x, batch_y = batch_creator(batch_size, train_x.shape[0], 'train')
         sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: dropout})
          if(step % display_step == 0):
                 batchv_x, batchv_y = batch_creator(batch_size, val_x.shape[0], 'val')
                 summary, loss, acc = sess.run([merged, cost,  accuracy], feed_dict={x: batchv_x, y: batchv_y})
                 train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

I looked into the created batches, which look fine.
batch_x is an array with the length of 2304 float values which represent the 48x48 image
batch_y is an array with the one_hot labels: [0 0 ... 0 1 0 ... 0 0]

This is my model:

```
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout, imgSize):
    with tf.name_scope("Reshaping_data") as scope:
        x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, imgSize, imgSize, 1], name="inp") #(?, 48, 48, 1)

    with tf.name_scope("Conv1") as scope:
        conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
        conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2) #(?, 24, 24, 32)

    with tf.name_scope("Conv2") as scope:
        conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
        conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2) #(?, 12, 12, 64)

    with tf.name_scope("FC1") as scope:
        fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]]) #(?, 9216)
        fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1']) #(?, 1024)
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1) #(?, 1024)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'], name="out") #(?, 43)
    return out
```

Thank you for your help!

PS: This is what some filters of the second convolutional layer look like (doesn't matter how many epochs later)

[image: conv2filter]

Comment: You are not running `init` within the session in order to initialise the variables. Are you not getting an error because of that?

Comment: I am running the init, I just forgot to copy&paste it. I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: Ah ok I see... Still, you are running the optimizer just once. Typically you will need to train over the whole dataset multiple times ("epochs") before actually seeing any progress towards your goal. Or is there some implicit loop?

Comment: It's running within a loop. I just tried to remove as much as possible to copy the code here

Comment: And (I know this is basic but I'm just thinking about usual suspects) I assume you are making sure that the `init` operation is _not_ being run within the loop, right? And also the session creation itself of course. As far as I can tell, the model looks fine to me; when I've had these kind of errors I find it's usually some simpler control flow mistake.

Comment: Yes. I added a few more lines of code and a example image of the filters. As the filter is only 5x5px its kinda small

Comment: Have you tried playing with your learning rate? For some reason I had to serverely reduce my Adam learning rate to get any progress.

Comment: Yes, I tried between 0.3 and 0.00001

Comment: Here is a screenshot from the tensorboard http://imgur.com/a/k8ZST There are two sessions run with different learning_rates. Change the rate would move the lines a bit but doesn't show any change while "learning"

Comment: Hmmm. That's a very odd graph as it's starting off ok and then just failing.How many epochs is that in your graphs you posted? Could you also post a picture of the graph from within Tensorboard. Make sure that everything is connected together correctly.

Comment: Here is the graph http://imgur.com/ue1n1E9 . The Conv2 Layer is so big because of the visualisation of the filter. For the Weigts/Bias init I tried, random_normal, truncated_normal and constant

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your network with cifar-10 database.

I'm afraid that the problem is caused by the huge parameters, especially in the fc1 layer. You can try reduce the kernel numbers, say divided by 2, in convolutional layers and use 4 or 6 as k in pooling layers to reduce spacial dimensions. Then you can reduce a lot the weights in fc1 layer.

And when parameters are numerous, be careful for the weight initialization. Use `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` or `tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / n))` for a better initilization.

After reducing the parameters and having a better initialization of weights, the loss on cifar-10 begins to converge. You can try this with your own database.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now added the xavier init to the weights and dramatically reduced the paramters (8 filter conv1, 16 filter conv2, pooling with 4 both times. If I run it then, I get this acc/costs http://imgur.com/a/Z4AA5 . For Training I use 80k 48x48 gray images splited 70:30 for validation. They are splitet in 43 one-Hot classes

Comment: Sorry, for my training with cifar-10, I used constant initialization 0.01 for biases too. What if you try this too? And if I still use random initialization for biases, there's a little chance (1/5) that training does not converge. And try to play with the learning rate and batch size too. For my case, I used 0.01 (with AdamOptimizer) and 128 respectively. Around 100~500 iterations, the loss obviously decreases.

Comment: I used your recommendations and played a bit with them without success. Here is what the results look like: http://imgur.com/a/HQBF6 . I also uploaded my complete code here: https://pastebin.com/vGj9bMf7 . The database I use can be found here: http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset  Thank you!

Comment: How do you split your training set and validation set? I want to say that whether you have already shuffled the whole dataset before splitting to training and validation set. If not, examples in the validation set are not seen by the network during training. And another suggestion, you don't have to train so long to have the results. Maybe 10K~30K iterations are fairly enough.

Comment: The filelists of the train/test data are already randomized before reading them with tensorflow.

Comment: I found that the database has a lot of images that are nearly exactly the same. They are just of different sizes. Plus that you use the fixed size (48*48) images, the dataset you are using is not as large as you think. I guess it is overfitting? but not very sure. Because the validation is always below 10%, like random guess. Maybe continue to try to reduce the parameters? kernel size to 3? FC1, 1024 to 256? And see the results from beginning to around 10K iterations.